# Klint and spotless: com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ParseException: Expecting a parameter declaration

Tags: kotlin, spotless

I'm getting weird exception when trying to run `./gradlew spotlessApply` on my project in Kotlin.

Class causing the problem:

```
import io.realm.RealmObject
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey

open class CurrentFluttering(
    @PrimaryKey var id: Long = 0,
    var currentCoinsHeap: Int = 0,
    var currentEarnedCoins: Int = 0,
    var startTime: Long = 0,
    var pauseTime: Long = 0,
    var time: Long = 0,
    var firstCycle: Boolean = true,
    var inBackground: Boolean = false,
    var currentMissedCoins: Int = 0,
    var isPaused: Boolean = false,
) : RealmObject()
```

Stack trace:

```
> Task :spotlessKotlin FAILED
Step 'ktlint' found problem in 'app/src/main/java/com/cfhero/android/model/state/CurrentFluttering.kt':
Expecting a parameter declaration
com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ParseException: Expecting a parameter declaration
        at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint.format(KtLint.kt:357)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.kotlin.KtLintStep$State.lambda$createFormat$1(KtLintStep.java:173)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterFunc.apply(FormatterFunc.java:31)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStepImpl$Standard.format(FormatterStepImpl.java:78)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStep$Strict.format(FormatterStep.java:76)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.Formatter.compute(Formatter.java:230)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.Formatter.applyToAndReturnResultIfDirty(Formatter.java:192)
        at com.di
```

Have anybody experienced same or similar problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found it. The problem was dangling ',' after last parameter in constructor (which Kotlin allows ).

```
var isPaused: Boolean = false, <- here ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)
) : RealmObject()
```

Comment: i think you just saved me from hours of debug and headaches 

Comment: Also a very common issue when you have a list/map defined like this: listOf(1, 2, 3,)

Answer (score 4):

This is caused due to the default ktlint version used by the plugin. As of this time it's `private static final String DEFAULT_VERSION = "0.35.0"` which does not support trailing commas, although kotlin 1.4 does. In fact they had updated it to `0.40.0` at some point but got some [formatting issues whiplash](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/745) and eventually [reverted](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/commit/da6325cddba5900bf99a7d103666e4a6b5491bc9) the changes.

If you want though you can manually point to the latest version with something like

```
spotless {
    kotlin {
        target '**/*.kt'
        ktlint("0.40.0")
    }
}
```